# What is the best way to set up base url for ajax request using Jquery?

Tags: ajax, jquery, cordova

Since phonegap is based on local html file it doesn't know about base url of remote server. I wonder what is the best way to set base url for ajax requests using jquery? Could anybody provide link to sample?

Currently i think about using jquery ajax prefilter.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When I dealt with this issue, I just put that information as a data-element on the  tag.

```
 <body data-base="http://mydomain.com"> ...
```

And then used that in building out the proper URL for a given request:

```
 //If pathOrURL is a relative path (e.g. /users/1), then we return a qualified
 // URL, such as http://mydomain.com/users/1
 // otherwise, we return the URL as is
 var qualifyURL = function(pathOrURL) {
   if (!(new RegExp('^(http(s)?[:]//)','i')).test(pathOrURL)) {
     return $(document.body).data('base') + pathOrURL;
   }

   return pathOrURL;
 };

 //Use this helper function when calling $.ajax
 $.ajax({
   url: qualifyURL(url), ... });
```

This worked great for my experience with Phonegap.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Our application works in phonegap mode and in browser mode too. So I don't want to change url generation and insert additional helper functions.

Comment: To be fair, this will work just fine in both browsers and in Phonegap.  It's simply doing explicitly what you are looking to do with preFilter.

Comment: The file I had was already using base href in head. So I voted for this one and the base href example. Of course, I just took $(document.body).data('base') from this example. Thanks!

Comment: if you are using jquery why don't you get the data element by
$(body).data("base");

Comment: Rookie question - why do you have var qualifyURL = function(pathOrURL) {} instead of function qualifyURL(pathOrURL) {}?

Comment: It's really stylistic.  Functions in JavaScript are first-class citizens and thus can be saved to vars and later called or passed as arguments. This is identical in this case to `function qualifyURL(...)`, but I like to be explicit about scoping in JavaScript (see http://blog.safeshepherd.com/23/how-one-missing-var-ruined-our-launch/)

Comment: I'd rather use my own wrapper on $.ajax.

Answer (score 40):

Both of the established answers have major drawbacks.  Requiring a function to be called to massage your URL every time you make a request is a lot of extra typing.  Adding a base tag to a page works great most of the time, but it causes some trouble if you're doing heavy duty work with SVGs.  Here's a simple solution that fixes all your URLs at once without using the base tag.

```js
var baseUrl = 'http://my.hardcoded.url/';
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {
        options.url = baseUrl + options.url;
    }
})
```

Comment: this is a hidden gem of an answer. great if you're dealing with legacy code that you don't have control of the $.ajax calls

Comment: the answer is fairly correct, what it doesn't work in Case the ajax Call define the beforeSend Callback :(

Comment: That's true, so you would need to put this JavaScript toward the beginning of the bootstrap process for your application

Comment: I like the idea, but this method should check if options.url is rooted or not. Otherwise rooted urls will be updated to invalid urls

Comment: Do we have something like this in plain Javascript?

Comment: Instead of using the XMLHttpRequest API directly, you could create a function that performs your requests and encapsulate the common logic there.

Answer (score 38):

The semantically correct way of doing this is to use the `<base>` tag:

```html
<head>
    <base href="http://mydomain.com/">
</head>
```

Then retrieve the value like this (unfortunately jQuery.ajax() does not pick up this value automatically):

```js
$('head base').attr('href');
```

Element reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE

Comment: While I agree that this is how you should do this, I don't always like using base href in head. I still voted for this and the data version. Thanks.

Comment: 'head base' didn't work as a selector. I just used base. Could also also head with find()

Answer (score 4):

Remove leading slash to make ajax url relative to base defined in header.

```
<head>
    <base href="http://base.com/">
</head>
```

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        settings.url = settings.url.replace(/^\//,'')
    }
})
```

Comment: Do we have something like this in JavaScript?

Comment: I think you'd have to to create a wrapper function around native fetch

Comment: Thank you @sam-s can you suggest me a sample example that would be very helpful for me.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also place a check to skip urls starting with http (probably cross-domain urls).

Make sure to place it right after including the jQuery file and before all ajax calls.

```
const baseUrl = 'http://example.com/sub/directory';

$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr, options) {
     if( options.url.indexOf('http') !== 0 ) {
        options.url = baseUrl + options.url;
     }
  }
});
```