# Virtual Directory issue in MVC4

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, virtual-directory

The testing server (IIS 6) places my application into a virtual directory.

So the root url is `http://www.testingserver.net/testsite/`

The regular routing goes fine, but it fails when I do REST Api calls. The Ajax calls `/Api/{controller}` return `http://www.testingserver.net/api/controller` instead of `http://www.testingserver.net/testsite/api/controller`, which ends up with a `404 Not Found`.

Can any one tell me how I can fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a client-side scripting issue. If you are using jQuery, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079801/173225

Basically, you just need to set the base tag. If you aren't using jQuery, the linked post should give you enough details to adapt to whatever you are doing.