# Base href confuse function on jquery and php includes

Tags: php, jquery, include, href, .post

I had the code

```
<base href = "http://localhost/thebaseaddress/">
```

If I am currently working on a folder inside that address eg `newFolder` and use that inside a file on this folder eg `index.php` does it affect my jquery `.post` method in accessing files from the parent directory like

```
<base href = "http://localhost/thebaseaddress/">
//jquery
$.post('otherFolder/file.php', { passed: passed }, function(data) { 
});
```

Note that the otherFolder/file.php was outside the newFolder directory and its on the parent directory.

The structure:

```
thebaseaddress
   newFolder
        index.php
   otherFolder
        file.php
        anyFile1.php
        anyFile2.php
```

Then also in the `index.php` I have this:

```
include 'otherFolder/anyFile1.php';
include 'otherFolder/anyFile2.php';
```

Should I use a `../` in `.post` or not anymore because I have that `base href`?
And also in `include` method, do i need to insert the `../`? Thankz..

Answer (score 0):

That base tag does not automatically resolve relative URL in your jQuery ajax request like it does on HTML document.

If you want to find workaround, it should be here
[What is the best way to set up base url for ajax request using Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728545/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-up-base-url-for-ajax-request-using-jquery)

They provide a way to concatenates the base href with any sub-url that you want to put into your ajax

Comment: No, all of them are in your HTML view, nothing to do with php