# Problem with calling WebApi controller from js ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have a problem in calling WebAPI controller by ajax statement.

Here is my code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/cartitems',
        type: self.cartItem.id == null ? 'post' : 'put',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: ko.toJSON(data)
    })
    .done(self.successfulSave)
    .fail(self.errorSave)
```

It produces an error 404 - file not found.

I've tested different possibilities and only one that works is using whole URL path.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://xx.yyy.zz.vvv/APP_NAME/api/cartitems',
        type: self.cartItem.id == null ? 'post' : 'put',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: ko.toJSON(data)
    })
    .done(self.successfulSave)
    .fail(self.errorSave)
```

Is it possible to not use the full path?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30766123

Answer (score 1):

I wonder whether, there is an error in ASP.NET MVC configuration.
On developer environment it works with simplified URL in ajax call.
And I can't believe that Microsoft forces developers to adjust URL address on every productive system.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the `Url.Action` construct will work. It ties into your routing configuration to produce a valid url.

In .JS Script

```
 url:'@Url.Action("api","cartitems")',
```

In .xxhtml

```
url:'@Model.YourPostabckUrlVariable',
```

Comment: Doh! You are correct. Perhaps putting the postback in the model.